# Check for Validation on 'submit' for a radio button on sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, edit-form

I have a SharePoint site where I need to check for validation on a "Messaging" field.

If the user leave it blank then form will show an alert.

I also attached an image what it looks like.

So far I have this code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if(!$("input[name='messaging']").is(':checked')  {
      alert("Please check message field");
   }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using??

Answer (score 1):

As you have not mentioned any conditions, I am assuming there are no conditions and you want your users to select either Yes or No for Messaging field.

**OOTB Solution**:

You can set the **Default Value** to your column so that it will always be selected either to Yes or No.

You can set the default value of column from column settings.

**Code Solution**:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    if(!$("input[name^='Messaging']").is(':checked')) {
        alert("Please Check Message Field.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Add this code on `EditForm.aspx` page of list either in Script Editor or Content Editor webpart.

Comment: this is on the edit form. so I can't put any default settings to it.

Comment: Try using the code in my updated answer and let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Make the default blank, that is: null.  The user is forced to choose something if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into script editor web part in edit form page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveItem(){ 
    if(!$("input[name^='Messaging']").is(':checked')) {
        alert("Please Check Message Field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

SharePoint provide the "**Yes/No**" column, I suggest you use this column to instead of the **Choice(Radio Buttons)** column.

[image]